# How do I set up per-user web directories in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, apache2

I have tried following the documentation on the [Apache2 site here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html) but I can't seem to find the `http.conf` and apache2.conf doesn't have the right lines in it and I am wondering if there's an easier way to do it in Ubuntu.

I would like `http://example.com/~rbowen/file.html` for example to go to the related home directory `public_html`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably far too late for you but if you use the following command:

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

And restart the apache2 service then the userdir module will be enabled.

Apache2.conf doesn't have the right lines as it uses these Includes directives instead:

```
# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
```

The "a2enmod" command adds modules to the mods-enabled directory (/etc/apache2/mods-enabled), which is also where you would look if you want to edit the config file for the userdir mod.